# Source code of View of Linked server sp_HelpText

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, source-code

How to use sp_helptext for view on the linked server ?

Answer (score 3):

There is an answer on SO: [SQL using sp_HelpText to view a stored procedure on a linked server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953952/3270427)

```
EXEC  [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_HelpText 'storedProcName'
```